# A little more info on why was this question closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Not sure why this question was closed, can anyone provide a little more info so I can maybe keep this from happening in the future?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827344/how-stable-is-net-async-ctp-3#comment11663155_8827344

Comment: What question is "this"?

Comment: Whoops. Added the link.

Answer (score 10):

It was closed as it is an opinion based, speculative question that will not be applicable in the near future.

The three possible answers, each of which are equally correct:

1. Yes, it is stable enough for production use.
2. No, it is not stable enough for production use.
3. Yes and no, it is sometimes stable enough and sometimes not stable enough.

Comment: Could it somehow be reworded into a question that is allowed?

Comment: Also, it says of questions, "We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise". That's exactly what I got as answers.

Comment: You got Jon and Stephen's opinions on the stability of the product, which aren't *bad* or *incorrect*. Just in 6 to 8 weeks when they ship it, their opinions won't matter. Or in 6 to 8 weeks when they ship an update *CTP N+1*, their opinions won't matter.

Comment: Much like when .NET 4.5 ships .NET 4.0 will be irrelevant I guess?

Comment: .Net 4.0 is a supported mainstream product. A *specific revision* of a Customer Technology *Preview* is pretty temporal.

Answer (score 4):

Not easy to see how this question could avoid falling foul of "the close police", given this:

> [Why are some questions closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#close#)
>
> - too localized
>
>   This question is unlikely to ever help any future    visitors; it
>     is only relevant to a small geographic area, **a specific    moment in
>     time**, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not    generally
>     applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet.

The moment CTP 3 is superseded, the question becomes worse than irrelevant.

Comment: +1, I agree this question should have been closed as Too Localized.

Comment: I don't think it'd become *worse* than irrelevant. And many technologies evolve, so it's not unique in that regard.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: it's a bit difference to ask about *Alpha Release X* of a product versus *Production Release Y* of a product. One of those two is going to have broad appeal and is much more likely to have future benefit to readers.

Comment: So no questions allowed specific to anything that might be updated? Well, that's pretty much everything short of theory. Ridiculous.

Comment: The thing is that CTP 3 is most likely going to be around until the end of this year. It's definitely not "a specific moment in time".

Comment: @CodyC: you asked the question, received an answer, and later your question was closed. There are 2 reasons why it should have been closed: (1) it was too localized and is not likely to be applicable in the future, and (2) the answers are subjective opinions.